# GNOME: gray line under "some" windows

Tags: gnome, 17.10

Yet another weird bug. Some windows, but not all of them, have a thick black/grey semitransparent line underneath them. Running Ubuntu 17.10 on Specter 360 4k Display.

It is the case for the file manger, and Rhythmbox but not firefox in the example bellow. Also happen with the terminal:
[image: Screen capture]

Session type is wayland

Video card is a integrated graphic

lshw output for display description:

```
VGA compatible controller product: Intel Corporation vendor: Intel Corporation physical id: 2 bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 version: 07 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 –
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Session type is wayland

Video card is a integrated graphic:
lshw output for display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 07
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0

Comment: Please edit this important information into the question.